# Dynamic Programming - Minimum number of coins needed for given sum

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, coin-change

After researching the Coin Change problem I tried my best to implement the solution. The code I have so far prints the minimum number of coins needed for a given sum. However, it does not print out the number of each coin denomination needed. This is what my code currently looks like:

```
public class Coins {

    static int minCoins(int coinValues[], int m, int target) {
       int[] totalCoins = new int[target + 1];
       int[][] numOfCoins = new int[target + 1][m];

       totalCoins[0] = 0;

       for (int i = 1; i <= target; i++) {
           totalCoins[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
       }

       for (int i = 1; i <= target; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
               if (coinValues[j] <= i) {
                   int previous = totalCoins[i - coinValues[j]];
                   if (previous != Integer.MAX_VALUE && previous + 1 < totalCoins[i]) {
                       totalCoins[i] = previous + 1;
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       return totalCoins[target];
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
       int coinValues[] =  {1, 5, 10, 20};
       int m = coinValues.length;
       int target = 26;
       System.out.println("Minimum coins required is "+ minCoins(coinValues, m, target) );
    }
}
```

I'm just very confused how/where I should populate numOfCoins[][].

Comment: Hint: whenever you find a better solution for amount `i` (innermost if) you have to update `numOfCoins[i]` to reflect this solution.

Comment: I have a few questions for you: 1. Are you familiar with the [Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html)? 2. Do you know what the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is? 3. Do you know what an [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) is? 4. Is this homework and if so would you be allowed to use any of the previous things I asked about?

Comment: @D.B. 1) I'm familiar with Queue, everything else is basically foreign to me. I'd consider myself an amateur in Java, there's still much I need to learn 2) I do know what the modulo operation is. 3) I'm also familiar with what an enum is, I just didn't consider using either for this implementation. 4) This is homework, however I already achieved the intended result (Minimum coins = #). I just wanted to go one step further and list the number of each denomination.

Comment: @Henry I see what you are saying, I'll see what I can do with that tip, thanks!

Comment: @Daveygravy12395 thanks for the answers. So I realize you already have a solution, but you can simplify your logic a lot using modulo. Perhaps that can be another step further for you. I suggest you focus on your goal - you want to map the value of the coin with how many coins of that value you need. Think about how you will represent this mapping, when to update it, etc. I asked about the collections because using a Map for this is simple.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that I implemented in Groovy using Euro denominations

```
class coinage {

def denoms = [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200]
def resultArray = []
def remainder
def largest
def newResult

def calculate(int amt) {
    def value = denoms.findAll({ element -> element <= amt})
    largest = value.last()
    resultArray.add(largest)
    remainder = amt - largest

    if (remainder == 0 || remainder == amt) {
        newResult = resultArray.size()
        println("Minimum number of coins required for this is: $newResult")
    } else
        calculate(remainder)
}
```

}

And to call it:

```
coins = new coinage()
coins.calculate(305)
```

Answer (score 0):

@user1523236 provides the greedy method which does not solve the general case. For example, if one removes the 1 denomination and calculates the change for 8.

Please take a look at, for example, [4.12. Dynamic Programming](http://www.openbookproject.net/books/pythonds/Recursion/DynamicProgramming.html), or [The dynamic programming alogorithm for CMP (change making problem)](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~yilan/TA/364/week3_solution.pdf). Both references provide general dynamic programming algorithms.

Comment: Ah, good point Jonathon, I should have tested my code with some other currencies rather than euro! thanks for the links, seems like I have a bit more studying to do.